# How do I split an EditText date into year, month and day integers for a Calendar object?

Tags: android, string, datepicker

I have a user entered date from a DatePicker that is on an EditText line on the UI.  I want to split the date into year, month and day so I can pass those 3 elements in a bundle.  I am getting this fatal exception message '"NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "2015 "'.  So it looks like it doesn't like the year split.  And maybe there is a space somehow after the 2015 that is causing the error.  What am I missing here?

partial Activity file:

```
...
private ListenerEditText fListenerEditText;
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String dateStr = fListenerEditText.getText().toString();
String[]dateParts = dateStr.split("/");
year = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]);
month = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0]);
day = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]);
c.set(year, month, day);
Bundle argsbundle = new Bundle();
argsbundle.putInt("year", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is a trailing space at the end of "2015 ".

The following will cause the same crash you see:

```
    Integer.parseInt("2015 ");
```

I would make a method like so:

```
public int safeParseInt(String number) throws Exception {
    if(number != null) {
        return Integer.parseInt(number.trim());
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("Date string is invalid"); 
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
try {
    year = safeParseInt(dateParts[2]);
    month = safeParseInt(dateParts[0]);
    day = safeParseInt(dateParts[1]);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // SHOW SOME MESSAGE TO THE USER
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  I added a space in EditText in the code so that is was I am retrieving.  The .trim() should work.  I have also used '.replace(" ","")' to remove spaces.  Is there any advantage to using .trim rather than .replace?

Comment: Trim only takes it from the ends, whereas replace will remove all space characters. In this instance it might not be a big deal, but they are not functionally the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested and it work so your split code is right.

```
String dateStr = "01/01/2015";
String[]dateParts = dateStr.split("/");
year = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]); //=> 2015
month = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0]); //=> 01
day = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]); //=> 01
```

Therefore, I think the problem is in your input data (`user entered date from a DatePicker`) = `dateStr`
You should check the format date that user entered before get data by using [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-check-if-date-is-valid-in-java/)
If you know your data always contains space, you should remove it by `trim()` method

And remember in

```
c.set(year, month, day);
```

01 for month is February so you should change it to

```
c.set(year, month-1, day);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

This method would be better.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf  =   new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try{
        Date date=sdf.parse("2015-09-28");
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        System.out.println("year="+calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"  month="+(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"  day="+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Nice.  I see SimpleDateFormat used many times.  Bit I've also read that it is not thread safe.  So are there any problems to using SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: @AJW this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414142/thread-safety-issue-with-simpledateformat